# Counting Actual Words In SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint List (only OTB access)..

I want to count the number of words (omit spaces) in a given cell in my list.

Is there an actual formula that can handle that?

Also, just an addition... is there an effinent way to count the words but omit words that are between parentheses? ex. (No one is home)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEN function.

Use the following formula in a calulated field:

=LEN([YourFieldName])

But space cannot be ignored, it will be treated as a character.

[image]